# Anchor tag not working with figure tag of bootstrap

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to redirect user to the link when he clicks on the figure but anchor tag doesn't work on clicking on the image. But the anchor tag with "CLICK HERE" works.

```
<a href="http://google.com">
<figure class="effect-ming">

<img src="http://example.com/dd.img" alt="Placeholder" />

    <figcaption>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">CLICK HERE</a>
    </figcaption> 
</figure>
</a>
```

css:

```
figure.effect-ming figcaption::before {
  border: 0px solid #fff !important;  
  bottom: 30px;  
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;  
  content: "";  
  left: 30px;  
  opacity: 0;  
  position: absolute;  
  right: 30px;  
  top: 30px;  
  transform: scale3d(1.4, 1.4, 1);  
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease 0s, transform 0.35s ease 0s;  
}
```

Comment: Each anchor tag need to be closed before opening a new one; *HTML 101*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did closed it just it didnt got indented properly on stack so didn't showed,, anyways I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <img src="http://example.com/dd.img" alt="Placeholder" />
</a>

<figure class="effect-ming">
    <figcaption>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">CLICK HERE</a>
    </figcaption> 
</figure>
```

I think this would be better. I moved the `figure` tag because the nesting was incorrect. If you want the image inside the figure, you can do that like this:

```
<figure class="effect-ming">


    <a href="http://google.com">
        <img src="http://example.com/dd.img" alt="Placeholder" />
    </a>

    <figcaption>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">CLICK HERE</a>
    </figcaption> 
</figure>
```

Comment: Problem remains. I think figcaption is on top of the img so cannot click anchor tag.